# JPA Auto Increment Property But Not an ID

Tags: jpa

Is it possible to have an auto-increment property but not an ID in JPA?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you read the JPA spec you find that @GeneratedValue is for primary key fields, so actually no. However DataNucleus JPA (that the user has selected) does allow @GeneratedValue on *any* field (extension to JPA spec)

Answer (score 3):

`@GeneratedValue` is not dependent of `@Id`.

In other words, yes, you can have an autoincrement that is not an ID.

You could have tried it yourself, though.

Comment: I tried @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE), will it generate a unique property?

Comment: Unique constraints have its own anotation (something like @Unique). GeneratedValue is just about how to automatically set the values of the field.

Comment: @SJuan76 Suggest read JPA spec section 11.1.17 "The GeneratedValue annotation provides for the specification of generation strategies for the values of primary keys."

Comment: I stand corrected, JPA only mandates that GeneratedValue works for primary keys. I checked my data here http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/generated but overlooked the fact that it was talking only about ObjectDB. Most notably, Hibernate seems not to support it.